# Trying to add shadow to entities using CesiumJS

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm trying to add a "shadow" of the in my replay but I'm not exactly sure if I should name that as a "shadow".

Please, look at my screenshot, you can see a red shadow below every entities (where I set the dots to highlight what I'm looking for)

You can see it live on https://ayvri.com/scene/z15y96gzjx/ck43xpxd500013e5ra7dh6s8e

I did try to find something documented for this feature, but so far, I didn't found. Neither on the Sandcastle.

I thought I would need to add particles to add a kind of tail, but I'm not even sure if it's the right direction to investigate on.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit 2** : To see clearly what I need to reproduce, you can also check this screenshot. Below the white trace, you can see a red gradient (from opacity 0 to 1) starting from the beginning of the trace.

[image: Red gradient under the trace]

Comment: Why did you down vote the question?

Comment: Shadow in Cesium is set based on sun position (in case your model does not has their own baked light source)

Comment: also other way if you do not use models, you  could use `Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider` and set `heightReference` to  `Cesium.HeightReference.CLAMP_TO_GROUND` it does not add real shadow but it clamp you entity to  ground.

Comment: @OlegBondarenko I edited my post but I didn't succeed to add anything new below my the CesiumBalloon for exemple

Comment: I have added post with working code

Comment: Unfortunately your solution does not fit with my need. I edited my post again.

Comment: I guess normal solution is not achieved in Cesium. Regular Shadows is working in Cesium but it based on sun position and it  is not that you described.  You could add model with appropriate  shaders but you have to  generate gltf model yourself.

Comment: Is there a tutorial somewhere to create our own model with shaders? I sent you a mail Oleg

Comment: I have adjusted my example, I guess it more close to your requirements now

Answer (score 1):

there is working example with ground tracer as I promised:

```
 var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
  scene3DOnly : true,
  shadows : true,
  timeline: false,
  terrainShadows : Cesium.ShadowMode.ENABLED
});
var terrainProvider = Cesium.createWorldTerrain();
viewer.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;


//---------------------- Start position of the plane ---------------------------
var startLongitude = -123.0744619, startLatitude = 44.0503706;
viewer.camera.flyTo({destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(startLongitude, startLatitude, 900)});


//--------------------------- CREATE A PLANE ENTITY ----------------------------
var plane = viewer.entities.add({
  //   position: new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(startLongitude, startLatitude, 600),  
  model : {
    uri : '../SampleData/models/CesiumBalloon/CesiumBalloon.glb',
     minimumPixelSize : 128,
        maximumScale : 20000,
    color : Cesium.Color.BLACK.withAlpha(0.5),

  }
  });


//------------ Array of (time, position) samples along the plane route ---------
var airPathArray = [];
//------------ Array of the points of the ground path under the plane ----------
var groundPathArray = [];


//------------ Initialize arrays ----------

  var timeNow = new Cesium.JulianDate.now();

  airPathArray.push({time: timeNow, degrees: {longitude: startLongitude, latitude: startLatitude},
                       position: new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(startLongitude, startLatitude, 600)});
  groundPathArray.push(startLongitude);
  groundPathArray.push(startLatitude);


//----------- Every 1 second a new point on the plane route is created ---------
var pathHandler = setInterval(function(){
  var timeNow = new Cesium.JulianDate.now();
  //timeNow = Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(timeNow, 2, new Cesium.JulianDate());
  // At start it takes initial coordinates



  // New next point coordinates are randomly taken

    var lon = airPathArray[airPathArray.length - 1].degrees.longitude + 0.0005 * (1 - Math.random());
    var lat = airPathArray[airPathArray.length - 1].degrees.latitude + 0.0005 * (1 - Math.random());
    airPathArray.push({time: timeNow, degrees: {longitude: lon, latitude: lat}, position: new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lon, lat, 600)});
    groundPathArray.push(lon, lat);
  // The maximum number of the route points is fixed
  if(airPathArray.length > 3){
    airPathArray.shift();
    groundPathArray.shift();
    groundPathArray.shift();
  }
  // The updated route is ready for visualization
  viewRoute();
}, 1000);


// Route visualization
function viewRoute() {
   // console.log(airPathArray[0].position);
  var trace = new Cesium.SampledPositionProperty();
    for(var i = 0; i < airPathArray.length; i++) {
    trace.addSample(airPathArray[i].time, airPathArray[i].position);
    }
  plane.position = airPathArray[0].position;
  //plane.position.setInterpolationOptions({
  //  interpolationDegree : 1,
  //  interpolationAlgorithm : Cesium.LinearApproximation
  //});
  plane.orientation = new Cesium.VelocityOrientationProperty(trace);
}


//------------------------ CREATE A GROUND PATH ENTITY -------------------------


function updatePositions() {
    var positions = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(groundPathArray);
    return positions;

}


var goroundPath = viewer.entities.add({
  corridor : {
    width : 50.0,

    material : Cesium.Color.BLUE.withAlpha(0.5),
    positions: new Cesium.CallbackProperty(updatePositions, false)
  }
});
```